# Returning repeated objects only if unique in Angular's ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am using Angular to iterate through some events from a JSON file. All is well except I am trying to show repeated event.month only once in the ng-repeat. The event.month returns the month and the day (ie October 28th) and the event.day returns the day of the week (ie Tuesday)

If there are 20 events under October 28th, I only want the first October 28th to show up in the view. I've tried a few different custom filters but can't seem to get it right.

I've tried picking apart the unique filter from https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter but with no luck.  I want this functionality but I don't want it to ommit the entire object, I just want it to omit the span if that date already exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

CodePen - http://codepen.io/drewbietron/pen/qLBit

Here is a dummied down version of what I'm working with.

```
<ul ng-repeat="event in events">

    <div> <!-- ONLY SHOW FIRST {{event.month}} - OMIT IF {{event.month}} EXISTS -->
        {{event.day}}
        {{event.month}}
    </div>

    <li>

        <span>{{event.time}}</span>

        <h2>{{event.instructor}}</h2>
        <p>{{event.info}}</p>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: span cannot be directly inside ul

Comment: Could you also attach the 'picking apart' of the angular filter unique ? Maybe there's something you missed ?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: @SrinivasPaila - I have edited my post and added the CodePen link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to omit the display of Month

Create custom filter as below:

```
app.filter('uniqueMonth', function() {
   var prevVal = null;
   return function(input) {
     if (prevVal !== input) {
       prevVal = input;
       return prevVal;
     }
   };
});
```

Update HTML:

```
{{event.month|uniqueMonth}}
```

Link to update codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/texiE

---

If you want to omit the entire date display Here is another link to codepen
http://codepen.io/pailas/pen/dDIxy

Create custom filter as below:

```
app.filter('uniqueDate', function() {
   var prevVal = null;
   return function(input) {
    if (prevVal !== input.month) {
      prevVal = input.month;
      return input.day + " " + input.month;
    }
   };
});
```

Update HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy: 'datetime'">
 <li>  
  <div class="date">
    {{event|uniqueDate}}
  </div>
  <span class="time">{{event.time}}</span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is working pretty well.  Is there a way to watch the filter so that when I am actually filtering classes it doesn't throw it off?  Right now if I run filters on list list of classes - the dates get thrown off.

Comment: I didn't get your question when you say the dates get thrown off?

Which filter your were referring to the first one or the later?

Comment: For the events - I also have the teacher.  If I filter the results by teacher - the first date of it's type is binded to the teacher, not the space it takes up.  Here's a CodePen with my current filters - If you clic one of the class types that's the first of it's date type - the remaining class types with that date don't inherit that date.

http://codepen.io/drewbietron/pen/dKjhe

Comment: Any luck?  I've been working on this for two days straight!  I've tried returning the dat as false if it's not the first of its type, but its not working.  Also how to update the scope after a filter?

Answer (score 1):

Use a groupby filter to group by whatever you want to group.

[Angular filters - groupby](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby)

Answer (score 0):

posting the answer here use the unique filter like this

```
 ng-repeat="event in events unique:'month'"
```

if you dont want whole object to be omitted

try something like

```
  <span ng-show="events[$index-1].month!=event.month">{{event.month}} </span>
```

or to more that it isnt first element

```
 <span ng-show="(!$first)?(events[$index-1].month!=event.month):true">{{event.month}} </span>
```

Comment: sorry me answer didnt got posted there , let me post again

Comment: The unique filter works, but it omits the entire object from the list, not just the date.

Comment: @Drewbietron , something like this can work i thnik?

Comment: Not quite getting it done.  {{event.day}} returns the day of the week.  {{event.month}} returns the month and the date.  I also have a {{event.uniquedate}} that will return 'Oct 28 2014' - So it makes sense to match either the month or the uniquedate.  Either of these with your suggestion still don't work though. I appreciate the help!

Comment: using span and mathing with prevois index, what does this produce?

Comment: and what about this?
<span ng-show="events.indexOf(event.month)==-1">{{event.month}} </span>

Comment: There are multiple of each dates.

Comment: give this span a try that is in comment?

Comment: I've added a CodePen link if you'd like to give it a shot.